# How to get Financial year by using expression in ssrs report

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

How to get Financial year by using expression in ssrs report.
Out put required (i.e FY 1617) by using from_Date or To_Date parameter.

Comment: Hi this expression (= "FY " + FORMAT(Parameters!from_Date.Value, "yy") + " " + FORMAT(Parameters!To_Date.Value, "yy")) gave me correct out put,but if my From_Date and To_Date parameter both pertaining in same year i.e From_Date='2017-04-01' and To_Date='2017-04-30' then it will give out put as FY 17 17. I want result as FY 1718 and if my To_Date pertaining from next year i.e 2018-01-30 then result should be FY 1718.

Answer (score 0):

Now your question becomes a bit tricky. Where do you want to put the output? What if your parameters contain more than 2 years? e.g. from = 2014 and to = 2017? It depends on your business requirement now. But anyway, below expression should give you some ideas, if year part of parameters is same, then we use the from parameter as the base, otherwise we use both from and to parameter:

```
= "FY" + IIF(Year(Parameters!FromDate.Value) = Year(Parameters!ToDate.Value), 
    FORMAT(Parameters!FromDate.Value, "yy") + " " + FORMAT(DATEADD(dateinterval.year, 1, Parameters!FromDate.Value), "yy"),
    FORMAT(Parameters!FromDate.Value, "yy") + " " + FORMAT(Parameters!ToDate.Value, "yy"))
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* it addresses the question.  Without that, your answer has much less educational value - remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hi that expression gave me correct out put,but if my From_Date and To_Date parameter both pertaining in same year i.e From_Date='2017-04-01' and To_Date='2017-04-30' then it will give out put as FY 17 17. I want result as FY 1718 and if my To_Date pertaining from next year i.e 2018-01-30 then result should be FY 1718.

Comment: Thanks, Now it is reflecting correctly as per my requirement.